# injecting multiple services in ONE inject method

Tags: angular, typescript

In my Route Module, I am using the `resolve` method. Take a look at this simple code snippet.

```js
            {
                path: ':id',
                component: RecipeDetailComponent, 
                resolve: {detail: (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => inject(RecipeService).getRecipes()[route.params['id']],
                data: () => inject(HttpService).fetchRecipes()                      
            }}
```

The problem is in the `data` method inside `resolve`, I want access to the `RecipeService`. I don't think it's as simple as `inject(HttpService, RecipeService)` and I couldn't find anything online. If anyone can tell me how to inject multiple services in a method, that would be great.

P.S: I tried looking at official Angular documentation, but I couldn't find how to do it.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I see no `data` method inside `resolve`, but I see the `data` property on the route config. Which do you now mean? If you mean really the `data` propery, then simply write a separate function somewhere in a service, where you inject the other service. And then call this function. You don't have to solve all with inline functions.

Comment: @derstauner , no `data` is a part of `resolve`.  If you notice there's one curly bracket up top and there's 2 in the bottom of the snippet.

Comment: you can call inject several times in any callback `data: () => {const a = inject(A); const b = inject(B); return a.doSomething(B, 'param2')}`